# friendly url in ZEND - several users

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, friendly-url, restful-url

How to create an application where you can use URLs like Facebook?

- app.dev/username
- app.dev/username/pictures
- app.dev/username/info
- app.dev/username/posts/post_333
- app.dev/username/posts/post_333/share

The application has other controllers with different URL's

- app.dev/events
- app.dev/site/contact
- app.dev/site/terms

When the controler does not exist, redirect to the profile controller

in application.ini

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Plugins"
resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Plugins_Profiles"
```

in Bootstrapp.php

```
protected function _initProfiles()
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(new Plugins_Profiles());    
}
```

in /library/Plugin/Profiles.php

```
class Plugins_Profiles extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $dispatcher = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getDispatcher();

        if (!$dispatcher->isDispatchable($request)) {

            $url = $request->getControllerName();

            $request->setModuleName('default');
            $request->setControllerName('profiles');
            $request->setActionName('url');
            $request->setParam('url', $url);

            /** Prevents infinite loop if you make a mistake in the new request **/
            if ($dispatcher->isDispatchable($request)) {
                $request->setDispatched(false);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

But I can not send variables
Ex: app.dev/username/posts/post_333/share

Any idea how I should proceed?

PS. Sorry about the grammar, I am Brazilian and I speak Portuguese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out Zend_Controller_Router_Route to get a clean url. Here are some links to get started with clean-url and zend route.

- [Url-routing in zend framework](http://blog.jebrini.net/post/1431025228/url-routing-in-zend-framework-for-dummies)
- [Simple Route example](http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_132/article_566-simple-zend-router-example.htm)
- [Documentation for Zend_Controller_Router_Route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html)